# I am trying to add values in a new column "id" but the values gets place down at the bottom of the table

Tags: postgresql

This is my SQL query

```
insert into details(city, state, zip, email) values
('Albuquerque','New Mexico',87112,'jdoe@example.com'),
('New York', 'New York' ,   10009 , 'jsmith@example.com'),
('Pheonix', 'Arizona' , 85006 , 'sthomas@example.com'),
('Pheonix'  , 'Arizona '  , 85015 ,  ' fbrown@example.com ' ),
('Seattle'  ,  'Washington '  , 98106 ,  'mdavis@example.com ' ),
( 'Denver'  ,  'Colorado '  , 80012 ,  'jwilson@example.com '),
( 'Austin'  ,  'Texas '  , 78703 ,  'jgarcia@example.com ' ),
( 'Denver'  ,  'Colorado'  , 80033 ,  'fclark@example.com '),
( 'Denver'  ,  'Colorado'  , 80122 ,  'blopez@example.com ' )
```

After this, when I try to add another column "id" and insert values to this column, values gets placed at the bottom as shown in the figure

```
alter table details add column id int; 
insert into details(id) values(111111),(111112),(111113),(111114),(111115),(111116),(111117),(111118),(111119)
```

[image: Click to view the picture]

I want to put the values of "id" corresponding to each city but it shows the value at the bottom.
It would be helpful if anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like you want to UPDATE a record, instead of inserting a new record. Use UPDATE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-update.html

Comment: There is no such thing as "the bottom" of the table. Row in a table have no order. The only way to get a consistent and guaranteed sort order is to use an `order by` when _selecting_ data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result.  You are inserting new rows with value for id and null for all other columns.  The order of insert is not stored.
You can do something like this:
`update details set id=111111 where zip=87112;`
for each row.

If you just want an id column and don't worry about what id is assigned to each row, you can do this:
`alter table details add column id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY  (START WITH 111111);`

This will create the id column as identity column (auto-increment) and populate it starting at 111111.  You cannot control what id is assigned to each row.

Best regards, Bjarni.